# Trouble updating UI with React useState when updating an array of items

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

Having a difficult time updating my UI with React and useState. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Basically what I am trying to do is simply remove an item that a user has added.

```
interface RedirectUrls {
 url: string;
}

const [redirectUrls, setRedirectUrls] = useState<RedirectUrls[]>([
 {
  url: ''
 }
])

function deleteRedirectUrl(url): void {
 let tmpUrls = redirectUrls
 tmpUrls = tmpUrls.filter(item => item.url !== url)
 setRedirectUrls(tmpUrls)
}

function handleChange (index, event): void {
 const tmpUrls = [...redirectUrls]
 tmpUrls[index].url = event.target.value
}

{redirectUrls.map((item, index) => {
 return (
  <div key={index}>
   <input type='text' onChange={(event):void => {handleChange(index,event)}}/>
   <div onClick={():void => {deleteRedirectUrl(item.url)}}>remove</div>
  </div>
 )
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points:

1. A component should return a single element. In your case, map returns an array of elements and I had to wrap the collection using an empty element (or [<React.Fragment>](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper))
2. Don't forget to set the `value` property to `input` element for the changes to reflect in the element.
3. As a best practice, use `const` instead of `let` when dealing with state variables, treat them as immutable, to avoid losing your changes especially when there are many state variables causing multiple renders
4. We should state the types as the file is typescript, you have missed specifying the types to arguments of your functions
5. Should call the setter once modifications are made

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface RedirectUrls {
  url: string;
}

const App = () => {
  const [redirectUrls, setRedirectUrls] = useState<RedirectUrls[]>([
    {
      url: 'firstUrl'
    },
    {
      url: 'secondUrl'
    }
  ])
  function deleteRedirectUrl(url: string): void {
    const tmpUrls = redirectUrls.filter(item => item.url !== url)
    setRedirectUrls(tmpUrls)
  }

  function handleChange(index: number, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
    const tmpUrls = [...redirectUrls]
    tmpUrls[index].url = event.target.value
    setRedirectUrls(tmpUrls);
  }

  return <>{redirectUrls.map((item, index) => <div key={index}>
    <input type='text' value={item.url} onChange={(event): void => { handleChange(index, event) }} />
    <div onClick={(): void => { deleteRedirectUrl(item.url) }}>remove</div>
  </div>)}</>;
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Christie I appreciate your feedback thank you. Couple of things when adding the value={item.url} to the input you can no longer type into it. Second if you click on the remove it removes the last item first then the second item and then the first item

Comment: Hey @GalacticRanger sorry about that. See the updated answer. I don't see the behaviour you are describing related to removing items. Are you referring to the same code?

Comment: Christie that did the trick thank you so much have been struggling with this for sometime now.

Comment: Glad to help @GalacticRanger :-)